# How to handle user cancel for OAUTH2 request in Teams messaging extension

Tags: oauth-2.0, botframework, microsoft-teams

The cancellation response from token.botframework.com is currently being displayed to screen like this:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "ServiceError",
    "message": "Missing required query string parameter: code. Url = https://token.botframework.com/.auth/web/redirect?state=d48fb60ae4834fd8adabfe054a5eff74&error_description=The+user+chose+not+to+give+your+app+access+to+their+Dropbox+account.&error=access_denied"
  }
}
```

How can I, instead, handle the cancellation gracefully? If the user cancels like this, I'd like to just have the auth-card-popup window close automatically.

This is for an action-type messaging extension app that I'm building. The sign-in process begins with an auth card. The bot is pointed at a Dropbox OAUTH2 connection. Here the relevant code that brings up the card:

```
const { TeamsActivityHandler, CardFactory } = require('botbuilder');
class MsgExtActionBot extends TeamsActivityHandler {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.connectionName = 'oauth2-provider';
    }

    async handleTeamsMessagingExtensionFetchTask(context, action) {
        if (!await this.isAuthenticated(context)) {
            return this.getSignInResponse(context);
        }
    }

    async isAuthenticated(context) {
        let tokenResponse = await context.adapter.getUserToken(
            context,
            this.connectionName
        );
        if (tokenResponse && tokenResponse.token) {
            return true;
        }
        if (!context.activity.value.state) {
            return false;
        }
        tokenResponse = await context.adapter.getUserToken(
            context,
            this.connectionName,
            context.activity.value.state
        );
        if (tokenResponse && tokenResponse.token) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    async getSignInResponse(context) {
        const signInLink = await context.adapter.getSignInLink(context, this.connectionName);
        return {
            composeExtension: {
                type: 'auth',
                suggestedActions: {
                    actions: [{
                        type: 'openUrl',
                        value: signInLink,
                        title: 'Please sign in'
                    }]
                },
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for reaching out to us We will investigate and if we require further information we will reach out. Best regards, Teams Platform

Comment: For cancellation you can implement an Interruption logic or you can call a new dialog by passing parameter to it, you need to set the redirect URI for this where you want to land after cancellation

Comment: Hmm. Thanks for taking the time to answer. I'm still unclear what to do, though. Where would the interruption logic go? Also, the redirect URI comes from the MIcrosoft's token framework I believe. It's definitely not something I'm generating. Maybe the auth-card-initiated process isn't the way to go? It doesn't seem to provide a way to handle non-200 responses.

Comment: Try this [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-howto-handle-user-interrupt?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-howto-handle-user-interrupt?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp)

Comment: That looks like that'd work for bot dialogs but I'm building a messaging extension. I think they use different flows. Maybe I'm wrong?